# How to list out all the nodes which are having common properties in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm having 4 nodes A,B,C,D having following properties,

```
 A:{works_in:"wipro"},{designation:"SE"}

 B:{works_in:"CTS"},{designation:"SSE"}

 C:{works_in:"CGI"},{designation:"SE"}

 D:{works_in:"UHG"},{designation:"SSE"}
```

Now i want to display all the nodes which is having similar properties either works_in/designation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
MATCH (a:YourLabel)
WITH a
MATCH (b:YourLabel)
WHERE a <> b AND (b.works_in = a.work_in OR b.designation = a.designation)
RETURN a, COLLECT(b) AS similar
```

This will initially match all your nodes and then use each node as the source for a new query. the `a <> b` will stop nodes matching themselves.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your response. what if i'm having more number of properties, can't we make it simpler than this?

Comment: Hi John, can we list out the property name which obtained a match with other nodes propery

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with following query, its working fine

```
   MATCH (A),(B)
   WHERE A. works_in =B. works_in
   RETURN A. works_in as Node1_and_Node2_working_in;
```

but the problem i'm facing here is each node is matching self. so result is coming
like,
                           Node1_and_Node2_working_in

```
                          wipro (A-to-A)

                          cts   (B-to-B)

                          cgi   (C-to-C)

                          uhg   (D-to-D)
```

Can we solve this with any built in command or property. if so please share your view on it.

Answer (score 0):

Hej Pavan, i would do it like this:

This Query will return all Node which works_in CGI or CTS and have a designation like SE or SSE.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.works_in =~ 'C.*' AND n.designation =~ '(?i)S.*' return n
```

This will return the Nodes B and C.
With the `=~` Operator you can use Regular Expressions in your Query

Maybe you also want to have a quick look in the Neo4J [Docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html)

If the query should only return Nodes which fit exactly to works_in, then use

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.works_in = 'WinPro'
```

or

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.designation = 'SE'
```

Another Idea would be to create Node with properties like Name and E-Mail and create Node like Skill (CGI, Java, WinPro) or Project and connect them with Relationships like WORKS_IN or is LOCATED_IN...

Patrick

Comment: Hi Patrick,thanks for your quick response. i need to display nodes which are having similar properties, but not specified properties. i think you got the difference.

Comment: Hi Patrick,can we list out the property name which obtained a match with other nodes propery?

Comment: @PavanKumarVarma you could do a Rest Call, e.g. curl -v GET localhost:7474/db/data/node/<id>/properties

It will return all properties with values..